# Unable to Install .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework, .net-3.5

Trying Windows 7, I am Unable to Install .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows 7 Ultimate..
First I downloaded the bootstrap version then the full version but nothing happens. 
I run the install, the UAC prompts and then nothing happens. 
**No error message or anything.**

Any idea or anyone with similar problem?

Answer (score 12):

It's already there.