# Why doesn't the .net framework 3.5 install on my PC?

Tags: windows-7, installation, .net-3.5

My PC is a DELL 380 - x86 with Windows 7 operating system

I am having a problem with installing SQL Server 2008 prompting an error message that the .net framework 3.5 is not installed. I tried to download and install. But nothing runs. 
How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Do you get any errors while installing .net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.Net Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows 7 not recognized by installers](http://superuser.com/questions/106647/net-framework-3-5-sp1-on-windows-7-not-recognized-by-installers) also see [Unable to Install .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows 7 Ultimate](http://superuser.com/questions/60044/unable-to-install-net-framework-3-5-sp1-on-windows-7-ultimate?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft now has tools for fixing the .Net stuff.
I have no idea if any of them could help, Just that a listing of all the options is usefull. Plus direct links to proper Install packages.

As always with any of this stuff there are System Requirements, procedures, and some reading to make sure that you have the correct item for the problem.

**Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool**
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135
The Article on it, and its revisions
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698555

**.NET Framework Setup Verification tool**

The Blog for it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx

Updated info on the verification tool http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/09/13/10349253.aspx

**.NET Framework Cleanup tool**
Artical with must read and downloads. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx

**.Net Fix-Its**

**Error code “0x80070643” or “0x643”** occur when you install the .NET Framework updates
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976982

Windows Update or Microsoft **Update repeatedly** offers the same update (some people it was Net updates that did not install)  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910339

Possibly usefull the Microsoft Visual Studio and **.NET Framework Log Collection** Tool
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=12493

They listened :-)  Myself I used the verification tool, then did not get anywhere. I had that situation where I could not install or re-install because Of a leftover registry or file item that the system believed it was installed. I used a Cleanup tool that tore out the whole thing, and was finnaly able to re-install repair one of my setups that way.

.NET Package **Installation Links** (mostly verified by me) These should ALL be Microsofts own site links.

[Microsoft .NET Framework Redistributable 1.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=96)

[Microsoft .NET Framework Version 1.1 Redistributable](https://web.archive.org/web/20210517233454/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26)

[Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20210420181316/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1639)

[Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3005)

[Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22)

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Standalone Installer)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718)