# How to remove net .NET Framework?

Tags: .net-framework

I've already try any tools provided by microsoft to remove or restore NetFramework but this just not work. There is no NetFramework in list of installed programms, but when i try to install it, it told me that this framework is already installed!

What i should do?

Comment: I compiled a list of things here http://superuser.com/questions/575716/why-doesnt-the-net-framework-3-5-install-on-my-pc/575764#575764  That is what I would use , plus some elvin magic .

Comment: why are you trying to install it when its already installed? that may give us a hint as to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution! Just install the offline installer of .NET Framework! The Web installer allways told me that .NET Framework is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

the .NET Framework 3.5 is a "feature", not a program, in more modern versions of Windows.

Go to the control panel and select "Turn Windows features on or off"  This will allow you disable the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thats not work! I try to unchek framework in "Turn Windows features on or off", but installer told me that framework is already installed!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .NET Repair Tool provided by Microsoft.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135

Once the .NET is fixed, you can try removing it.  The .NET repair tool might even provide the ability to remove the .NET framework.